# ERC20 Unstaking function not working

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, staking

I am building a staking contract that accepts an ERC20 token set by the owner.

```
contract ECommerce {
    IERC20 token;
    ....
token = IERC20(**"I insert the token address here"**);
```

Here are some important functions:

**Stake token**

```
     function stake(uint256 _tokenamount) public returns(bool) {
           require(_tokenamount <= GetAllowance(msg.sender), "Please approve tokens before transferring");
           token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenamount);
UserTokenBalance[msg.sender]+=_tokenamount;
           return true;
       }
```

**Allowance checker**

```
 function GetAllowance(address _tokenOwnerAdd) public view returns(uint256){
       return token.allowance(_tokenOwnerAdd, address(this));
   }
```

I get the error with the unstake function:

**unStake token**

```
     function unstake(uint256 _tokenamount) public returns(bool) {
           require(_tokenamount <= UserTokenBalance[msg.sender], "You cannot unstake more than you staked");
           token.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _tokenamount);
UserTokenBalance[msg.sender]-=_tokenamount;
           return true;
       }
```

> The unstake function just says: "Error will be thrown in contract
> execution"

Yes, the contract does have gas.

Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the user approve tokens to spend from your own contract. The user would have to sign a transaction to the token itself, calling `approve` with your contract address. (otherwise you could just steal all his coins..!)

Usually how it's done is that your front end will issue for the user 2 txs: one to the token to approve your contract, and second to your contract to pull the tokens.

Additionally, to use this approve-and-pull mechanism, you need to use `token.transerFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)`. The way you're doing it - `token.transfer(address(this), _tokenamount)` - will transfer tokens from your contract to itself.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. I will test it now and get back to you

Comment: Ok, staking works now but unstaking still seems to be a problem - it throws an error. I did  send Ether to the contract so there is gas - any advice?


'''
function unstake(uint _tokenAmt) public returns (bool){

require(_tokenAmt <= userTokenBalance[msg.sender], you cannot unstake more than you have stakes):
token.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _tokenAmt);
...
}
,,,

Comment: No, I cannot understand it like this. If you want you can make a new question with all the details (like you supplied all details in your original question) and then I might be able to help.

Comment: Hi, I updated this question

Comment: I would log UserTokenBalance[msg.sender] and make sure your balance is enough

Comment: I is; when I check UserTokenBalance[msg.sender] in remix, it is well above what I am trying to withdraw